# Drawing Circles extremely inconsistent?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For a school project, I'm using Python Turtle to make an "avatar". I have curly hair, so I wrote some code to draw a black half-circle, every 10-ish degrees it stops, and makes a much smaller circle of the same color, then resumes.

The code *works?* It does what it's supposed to do for the first 3 smaller circles, but it seems to be random on the 4th smaller circle. I've even set the degrees to draw the half-circle to 10000 and it only completed the 4th smaller circle by 3/4ths.

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle() #defining Turtle

def drawHair():
    ##debug, getting turtle to needed pos.
    t.color("Moccasin")
    for x in range (90):
        t.forward(2.5)
        t.left(1)
    t.setheading(90)
    ##

    t.color("Black")
    cTime = 0                           #"Timer" to determine a smaller "Curl"
    for x in range (180):               #SUPPOSED to draw a half-circle
        t.forward(2.5)                  #
        t.left(1)                       #
        cTime = cTime + 1               ##For every "Degree" in the main half-circle,
                                        ##add 1 to the "Timer"
        print("circle = " + str(cTime)) #debug
        if cTime == 10:                 #If "Timer has reached it's limit"
            cTime = 0                   #Reset timer
            for x in range (360):       #Draw a full, smaller circle
                t.forward(-0.4)         #
                t.left(1)               #
```

I *know* this is more complicated than it should be. I simply want to know why this problem happens and how to fix it.

EDIT : https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9kF6.jpg (Proof)

Comment: Your code works on my computer though. Can you post a screenshot of the drawing it produces?

Comment: There ya go, edited the question.

Comment: Did python just stop there? It should keep running. It drew lots of curls on my computer.

Comment: Yea, no matter what value I put it never even attempts to finish the 4th circle

Comment: The editor that you are using looks unfamiliar... Are you doing this on an online platform?

Comment: Y'know what? I should probably mention that i'm using repl.it... That might've been important.

Comment: It is possible that repl.it has a time limit for your code to run, or a limit on how many times you can draw new stuff. Can you try running it on your computer, locally?

Comment: I can try, what editor are you using? My school has been exclusively using repl.it for Python, so I've never really _needed_ a standalone editor.

Comment: You can just use IDLE, which can be downloaded along with Python itself, [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Another option is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/education/?fromMenu#lang=python&role=learner), which is a more advanced editor.

Comment: So i'm trying PyCharm and when I run the snippet provided here, the Turtle window opens then immediately closes, sometimes going unresponsive and crashing. I doubt it's a feature...

EDIT: Nevermind then, just saw the answer posted recently.

Comment: Try IDLE then... :( Anyway, my answer here should also work on repl.it, as I have greatly sped up the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing *way* too many draws, which repl.it seems to not like. There is actually a [`circle`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.circle) method in `Turtle` that draws circles (and semicircles) for you! This is a lot faster than drawing it with for loops.

Using this, and a bit of maths, I have come up with this code:

```
import turtle
from math import cos, sin, pi
t = turtle.Turtle() #defining Turtle

def drawHair():
    ##debug, getting turtle to needed pos.
    t.color("Moccasin")
    t.radians()
    t.setheading(-pi / 2)
    t.circle(140, extent=pi) # bottom semi circle
    t.color("Black")
    t.circle(140, extent=pi) # top semi circle
    for x in range(19):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(cos(x*pi/18)*180+140, sin(x*pi/18)*180) # position for each curl
        t.setheading(x*pi/18 + pi/2)
        t.pendown()
        t.circle(20)
drawHair()
```

I've basically used the parametric form of the equation for a circle. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I've ran your code a few times and i'm curious about it. What piece of code draws the black half-circle? I've commented out, and even temporarily deleted the "top semi circle" line and that changes nothing.

Comment: @ThomasFleming Really? Did you not see the big black semicircle that is the tangent to all the small circles in the screenshot? If you remove the "top semi circle" line then that big semicircle disappears.

Comment: No need to be hostile.I'm using `t.begin_fill()` because this shape unfilled looks ugly to me. I'll ask somewhere else though since i'm being an annoyance. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Tne problem may be that you're drawing circles that are too detailed for repl.it -- although your code *should* work, even Python turtle's own `circle()` function uses only 60 segments, not 360, to draw a circle.  Even less for small circles.

Here's a rework of your code to draw all your circles in fewer segments, synchronized with your desire to draw the smaller circles every 10 degrees:

```
import turtle

def drawHair():
    # get turtle to needed position
    t.color("Moccasin")

    for x in range(15):
        t.forward(15)
        t.left(6)

    t.color("Black")

    for x in range(36):  # draw a half-circle
        t.forward(12.5)
        t.left(5)

        if x % 2 == 0:  # every other segment of the outer circle
            for _ in range(72):  # Draw a full, smaller circle
                t.forward(-2)
                t.left(5)

    t.color("Moccasin")  # finish the face outline

    for x in range(15):
        t.forward(15)
        t.left(6)

    t.hideturtle()

t = turtle.Turtle()

drawHair()

turtle.done()
```

I seems to work on repl.it for me.  (Though repl.it does have lengthy pauses.)  And the circles still appear round despite the reduced segments:

[image]

I assumed that you weren't allowed to use the `turtle.circle()` method, but if you can, as @Sweeper assumes, then this becomes a much simpler program:

```
import turtle

def drawHair():
    # get turtle to needed position
    t.color("Moccasin")
    t.circle(143, 90)
    t.color("Black")

    for x in range(18):  # draw a half-circle
        t.circle(143, 5)
        t.circle(-23)  # draw a full, smaller circle
        t.circle(143, 5)

    t.color("Moccasin")
    t.circle(143, 90)
    t.hideturtle()

t = turtle.Turtle()

drawHair()

turtle.done()
```

You'll see the circles are slightly cruder than my first example but you can tune this using the `steps` parameter of `turtle.circle()`.